# Flask project threading

Tags: multithreading, sockets, flask, websocket

I am trying to create a Flask project that displays live data received from a c++ project through a unix socket. The data should be updated live without having to refresh the page with the data that are read from the unix socket every 1s.
The problem encountered lies in using flask-socketio with eventlet while also streaming the data with socketio.emit() so data can be updated using javascript and ajax/socketio.

As a wrap-up I`m aiming for simple flask app that reads from a unix socket and uses that data to plot charts.
Also, web programming is a new thing to me.

After trying to use both flask-socketio and eventlet in the following manner:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet')
if __name__ == '__main__':
eventlet.monkey_patch()
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I get the following error: "RuntimeError: You need to use the eventlet server. See the Deployment section of the documentation for more information" and the application does not crash but does not work either. I assume it is stuck while reading from the unix pipe. Also, I cannot find any information about using both of these.

Is it possible to run the flask project using eventlet and flask-socketio? Is it possible to only use one of them to achieve a multithreaded program? If not, what else can be used to achieve a threaded transmission as follows: unix-socket -> flask app -> (whatever to be used so I can update the data live on the webpage without having to refresh it - from what I've read that's called polling).

Comment: please don't post images of code, post the code as text